# Opencart sql query from unique table

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I have a strongly modified opencart store.
I would like to display all products from subcategories on the main category pages. This is the half-done code from my product model file.

```
    } else {
        $cat_sql = "SELECT `category_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE `path_id` = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        $cat_query = $this->db->query($cat_sql);
        if ($cat_query->num_rows) {
        $sql .= " AND (p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        foreach($cat_query->rows as $cat) {
        $sql .= " OR p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$cat['category_id'] . "'";
        }
        $sql .= ")";

        } else {
        $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        }
    }
```

It's supposed to display those products.

But now I have another table for multiple parent categories.

**My question is**: how can I display the products from the subcategories, where I just have `parent_id` not `path_id`.

The multiple category table is simple.

`category_id / parent_id`

How can I modify the code above so that it displays all products from subcategories where they don't have `path_id` only `parent_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to modify sql just pass extra parameter `'filter_sub_category' => true` and it will list out all the product including child category

```
$filter_data = array(
'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
'filter_sub_category' => true
);
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this method is good. Just my problem is that I have an extension, with this extension you can assign multi parent category for subcategories. This extension add to database and extra table. Where save the category_id and their parent_id. Where I use this extension the way above is don't work.